# Rob LaPlaca selectbox.js not working for setting value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

I have little weird issue with [`Selectbox.js`](http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/)

I am converting an existing selectbox with below code

```
var sb = new SelectBox({
    selectbox: $(this),
    height: 140,
    width: "100%"
});
```

Here `$(this)` is `$('#sltCountry')` like below

```
<select id='sltCountry' name='sltCountry'>
    <option value="1">India</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
    <option value="3">UK</option>
</select>
```

Now what happens that I want to set selected value for `$(this)` but as I have used `SelectBox()`, I am not able to do that.

select box is converted into `<dl>` tags. So explicitly I cannot set value for that what I want to set.

Function I am using to convert all `select` boxes into SelectBox() type select boxes.

```
function newSelectBox(obj) {
    $(obj).each(function() {
        var sb = new SelectBox({
            selectbox: $(this),
            height: 140,
            width: "100%"
        });
    });
}
```

> Usage: newSelectBox($('select'));

I have spent many hours to do this but could not succeeded.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: `$(this)` according to you what should it be? your element you want to apply selectBox which is doesnot seem to be like that.

Comment: can you add the selector or the context in which it is getting executed?

Comment: Did you tried change `$(this)` with `$('#sltCountry')` ?? Maybe your problem is on the scope

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, I cannot do that because I have created a common JS function which automatically searches for `$('select')` elements and converts them into new style.

Comment: So share that loop function.

Comment: If you need to define a selected value by default, change the native `<select>` and the plugin make all automatically. `<option selected value="1">Default selected</select>`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude any luck?

Comment: I don't know what are you asking, sorry. I don't know what you need to achieve. The code you sharing is correct. Provide a working example. Read this carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve